# Configuring a package that was downloaded using apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, apt

I have to reconfigure PHP with some extra options but since I downloaded it on Ubuntu using apt-get I can't seem to find the source anywhere (php -i points the source to a tmp folder which no longer exists).

Is there anyway to reconfigure without having to use apt-get -o=?

One of my issues is that I need the version to say the same (5.3.2) doing an apt-get now tries to download 5.3.3

Comment: you will have to go download the source manually to reconfigure it, also finding a specific version can sometimes be tricky... what package are we talking about?

Comment: The package was PHP5 (which since I first downloaded it has went up by a point).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Christopher's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2755/configuring-a-package-that-was-downloaded-using-apt-get/2762#2762) made me go read the manpage and **you can specify the version** when downloading the source with apt-get.

From the apt-get [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get).

> **source**
>
> ...
>
> A specific source version can be retrieved by postfixing the source
>   name with an equals and then the
>   version to fetch, similar to the
>   mechanism used for the package files.
>   This enables exact matching of the
>   source package name and version,
>   implicitly enabling the
>   APT::Get::Only-Source option.
>
> Note that source packages are not tracked like binary packages, they
>   exist only in the current directory
>   and are similar to downloading source
>   tar balls.

so running

```
apt-get source php5=5.3.2
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 6):

`apt-get source $PACKAGE=$PACKAGEVERSION` will download the source for a package to the current directory.

`apt-get build-dep $PACKAGE` will install the build dependencies for a package so you can build it.

`dpkg-buildpackage` will build it.

`dpkg -i $PACKAGEFILE` will install a package file. (.deb)

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the configuration that happens when you install the package, then

```
dpkg-reconfigure php5
```

If you mean you want to recompile the package with different compile-time configuration, then, if the package is still available from your configured sources:

```
apt-get source php5=5.3.2
```

If the package has fallen off the repositories, you'll have to search for it on the web. All Debian packages are archived at [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org/).